# Making a list for functions

Tags: c#, wpf, list, mvvm

In my view model I have some mathematical functions like add, subtract. In my user interface I have two text boxes which will contain an input and then there is a combobox. This combobox will contain name of all the mathematical functions (add, subtract). And on OK button I want selected function to be executed. How I can do this. I mean how I can display list of function names in combo box? I can display string in there, but how functions names. And selected function as well.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Actions}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAction}" />
```

View Model

```
public IEnumerable<string> Actions
{
    get
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("Add");      // Instead of adding strings, I want to add functions.
        list.Add("Subtract"); 
        return list;
    }
}

public int AddFunction()
{
    return numberA + numberB;
}

public int SubtractFunction()
{
    return numberA - numberB;
}
```

Comment: You want to add functions in your `ComboBox` or names of functions? ie. `string`s.

Comment: Function names actually. In this case combo box will contain AddFunction, SubtractFunction in it.

Comment: In simple words it should be like that I select function from combo box and then click OK. On OK click I don't check what is value of combox box. I just do is that selectedAction.Exceute(or something like this). I don't want to put if else checks that if combox box string is add then execute this else do that.

Comment: @FaisalHafeez I am not sure why you really want to do it when using switch would be much simpler but what you are looking for is called [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: What you seem to be asking for is a concept called Reflection. However Reflection is not a simple topic at all. If possible I suggest you steer well clear of Reflection unless absolutely necessary. Perhaps you could describe what you are trying to achieve as opposed to this solution you have, which I can assure you is going to be really painful. Once you have the method, it is going to be very hard to invoke it, then also really hard to bind it to your view. PLUS it feels like it is not very MVVM.

Comment: List of functions will change for different views. I have a list of many functions and for different view combo box will contain different functions. And I don't want to add same code (with only some changes) for different views.

Comment: @FaisalHafeez what do you mean by Views?

Comment: In final application there will be objects of different types, and each type will have separate view containing his actions (from all actions list) and other things related to object. One object has only two actions and one has 18, so if I place switch then for all objects view model I have put code (repetitive).

Answer (score 1):

Below a example that could help:

TODO:
1. Result should to binded to another textblock in the UI
2. ComboBox_SelectionChanged should be done via ICommand. Ref: [mvvm-binding-treeview-item-changed-to-icommand](http://jacobaloysious.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/mvvm-binding-treeview-item-changed-to-icommand/)

```
    public IList<MyComboboxItem> Actions
    {
        get
        {
            var list = new List<MyComboboxItem> { new MyComboboxItem(AddFunction), new MyComboboxItem(SubtractFunction) };
            return list;
        }
    }

    public int numberA { get;  set; }
    public int numberB { get; set; }

    public int Result { get; private set; }

    public void AddFunction()
    {
        Result = numberA + numberB;
    }

    public void SubtractFunction()
    {
        Result = numberA - numberB;
    }

    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var comboboxItem = e.AddedItems[0] as MyComboboxItem;
        if (comboboxItem != null)
            comboboxItem.Action.Invoke();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;




  public class MyComboboxItem 
  {
    public Action Action { get; private set; } 

    public MyComboboxItem(Action action)
    {
        this.Action = action;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Action.Method.Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So what you want is to have a list of delegates, and then a converter that will convert a delegate into method name.

In your ViewModel, have the Actions property returns a list of delegates. Use the predefined Func which is a method that takes no argument and returns int:

```
public IEnumerable<Func<int>> Actions
{
    get
    {
        List<Func<int>> list = new List<Func<int>>();
        list.Add( AddFunction );
        list.Add( SubstractFunction );
        return list;
    }
}
```

Next, implement a converter. Typically, a converter is part of the "View" so put it in the code behind cs file. This conversion convert `Func<int>` to string, and it uses reflection to do that:

```
[ValueConversion( typeof( Func<int> ), typeof( string ) )]
public class FnConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        Func<int> fn = value as Func<int>;
        return fn.Method.Name;
    }

    public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Finally, you need to use the converter in the XAML. But in order to do that, you need to specify the item template of the combo box, where the converter is applied.

```
<!-- earlier in code define the converter as a resource -->
<Window.Resources>
    <src:FnConverter x:Key="conv" />
</Window.Resources>

...

<!-- now the combo box -->
<ComboBox Margin="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Actions}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource conv}}"  />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Saying that, I think an even more elegant solution would be to keep a list of MethodInfo in the view model. Generate this list using a custom attribute. Below some code. Note the following points:

1. PresentingAttribute is a custom attribute. It derives from System.Reflection.Attribute. It has nothing. You can if you want add parameters such as "Label", "Description", etc.
2. Decorate the methods that you want in the combo box with `[Presenting]`
3. Now, Actions uses reflection. Note the 'Where' and the lambda for the filter predicate, which returns only methods that has our custom attribute.
4. You'll have to modify the converter to take MethodInfo.

```
namespace SO
{
    class PresentingAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }

    class FnVM
    {
        public int numA { get; set; }
        public int numB { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<MethodInfo> Actions
        {
            get
            {
                return typeof( FnVM ).GetMethods().Where( minfo => 
                    minfo.GetCustomAttribute( typeof( PresentingAttribute ) ) != null
                );
            }
        }


        [Presenting]
        public int AddFunction( )
        {
            return numA + numB;
        }

        [Presenting]
        public int MulFunction( )
        {
            return numA * numB;
        }

    }
}
```